# Math rendering errors?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Recently,and my browser and configuration have not changed, hardly any maths formulas are exhibited in the question.  Sometimes there is not even a red phrase about an error...nothing to indicate that the formula or symbol is missing.  Has the site changed its rendering or something? 
     And this is recent.

OS is Redhat Linux 17 like for years.  Browser is Mozilla firefox 37.0.2, like for years.  And I didn't have this problem last week...

Comment: 1. Try restarting your computer. 2. Indicate your OS and browser in the question. 3. Screenshots would help. 4. Is the problem consistent, across all posts, or only sporadic? 5. This is probably best asked at [meta.se].

Comment: Well, thanks.  I kept searching for other similar queries here and eventually found a helpful suggestion:  reload the page.  This makes a great difference.  Perhaps that is the real solution.  We'll see.  Still, it is odd that this was never necessary before.

Comment: That could be any number of changes both on the site (which did get a redesign on ~14 January) or on your setup. Again, this issue will likely be impossible to resolve unless you provide better documentation about what's going on - but if you're managing it then that also sort of works.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty reboot to fix a javascript error? :\

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though reloading the page resolves the issue.  But this never used to be necessary.  I will keep myself posted, and thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: If it happened once or twice, and you reloaded the page and things worked fine after that, sure, we can consider it resolved (in the sense of not being reproducible, so there's nothing we can do). If you _always_ have to reload the page every time to get it to work, that's still a bug.